# Use of __uuidof operator gives extension use warning

Tags: c++

I'm following a DX11 example and I would like to clean up my code so as not to have any warnings. I'm currently trying to remove this one:

In this code:

```
result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory),
                           reinterpret_cast<void**>(&factory));
```

I get the following warning:

```
d3drenderclass.cpp:41:32: warning: extension used
```

I'm not even sure what this is, and have not been able to find much help online. How should I type this code in order to get rid of the warning?

If this warning is unavoidable by rewriting the code, can I turn the warning off? I'm suing Qt Creator.

Comment: look like you use not *CL.exe* (more known as *msvc*) compiler

Comment: I'm using MSVC2017 x64, that is correct

Comment: *cl* always write warning number in next format  *filename(line): warning Cxxxx: ...* - what is concrete warning number Cxxx ?

Comment: so this is not from cl but from another tool

Comment: But it is. I know now what you mean, but there is no number. The more complete message reads "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - Wlanguage-extenstion-token". Does this help?

Comment: this not compiler warning. you run some code diagnostic tool in your VS.

Comment: But isn't "Wlanguage-extenstion-token" a compiler flag?

Comment: Maybe you are using `clang-cl` in Visual Studio? Looks like a clang warning.

Comment: "Wlanguage-extenstion-token" a compiler flag? - again and again - this is not warning from CL but from another tool

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator and to be honest I don't know what is clang-cl, so it is possible. I'm starrting to think this is a IDE thing and not a compiler thing like @RbMn suggested....

Comment: *IDE thing* not of course. but you need check project and solution settings. are some sdl checks and so on.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html - https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wlanguage-extension-token

Comment: Yeah, there was an option hidden inside the message (which showed up in the IDE) which looked like a close button. On pressing it there was some message (too fast and I didn't get to read it completely) saying something like "Saved CLANG Project Settings" and then the warning stopped. It must have done something similar to what you were suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can do one of two (maybe more) things. If you want to use the `clang-cl` compiler, surround the 'offending' line with warning off/on pragmas:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wlanguage-extension-token"
result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory),
                           reinterpret_cast<void**>(&factory));
#pragma clang diagnostic warning "-Wlanguage-extension-token"
```

Or, alternatively, switch to the MSVC compiler by going to the project "General" settings and select the `Visual Studio …"` Toolset.

Comment: Marking is as right, though its only partially right. I'm currently using Visual Studio toolset. So unless Qt Creator uses two tools somehow, I'm not sure why this happens. I haven't found any info online....

Comment: You've said it's `VS2017` that you're using, and I think the 'official' inclusion of the `clang-cl` toolset came only with `VS2019` - so maybe there is another way that `Qt` is doing it. Are you using a makefile?

Comment: No. My installation process consisted of install the C++ compiler usin MSVC2017 and the installing Qt. If you do things in that order everything becomes automatically set for you, so just selecting the MSVC Compilere and Pressing play will get you a running application in Qt Creator. That's about the extent of my knowledge. Now, during the build process QtCreator DOES create a Makefile, I thought clang was a different compiler, though

Comment: @aarelovich - clang **is** a different compiler! But how that warning (which is pure clang) came about is the mystery, here?

Comment: Got no idea, honestly. But at leas there is a way to make it go away....

Comment: You certainly want to use [#pragma clang diagnostic push/pop](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas) instead of unconditionally enabling a warning.

Comment: any chance this warning has been triggered by the 'clang-model' component of QtCreator ?