# Building DIA code fails with LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_DiaSource

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dia-sdk

Following the instructions from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77896744/1889329) this program compiles but fails to link:

```cpp
#include "dia2.h"

int main() { auto const clsid { CLSID_DiaSource }; }
```

The full error diagnostic is

> ```
> main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_DiaSource
> ```

Where is this symbol defined and what do I need to do to make the linker happy?

Comment: C or C++? Please tag this with the language you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This question (and answer) applies to **both** C and C++. There is no difference. It is the whole *"C/C++"* thing dogmatists don't get: C and C++ share a whole bunch, like the build model. This Q&A is down to the build model. And no, the proposed duplicate doesn't answer **this specific question** in any helpful way.

Comment: Declarations like `int foo();` in C and C++ differ in ways that affect the linking. Also, if you want to change rules, head over to meta.stackexchange.com or make a change request to the two language tags. Just breaking the rules and not even giving a rationale why they don't apply to your particular question is going to get you this kind of question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt *"Just breaking the rules and not even giving a rationale"* - I just did: C and C++ share the same build model (ignoring C++ modules, which this question isn't using). If you feel strongly about closing this question and presenting users with the *"here are ALL LEGO® pieces known to mankind. You go figure out which ones to pick and how to combine them. FU."* treatment, go ahead. I'm not invested enough here anymore to want to fight for quality.

Comment: You seem not to be interested in the rationale I gave why the actual language is important either. Let's just part here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIA's interface and class IDs are defined in a static library called `diaguids.lib`. It needs to be passed as an input to the linker. An easy way to do this is via a [`comment` pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp):

```cpp
#include "dia2.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "diaguids")

int main() { auto const clsid { CLSID_DiaSource }; }
```

This isn't sufficient, though. The linker will still error out with

> ```
> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'diaguids.lib'
> ```

To fix this the (platform-specific) library path must be set in the build environment. The DIA SDK chose an odd layout and naming scheme making this somewhat tedious to set up. This isn't just me, either: The [Dia2dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/dia2dump-sample) sample fails to link for any platform that isn't x86.

In Visual Studio, the library directory can be added by right-clicking the project, selecting *"Properties"*, and navigating to *"Configuration Properties"* -> *"VC++ Directories"*. The *"Library Directories"* configuration needs to be updated to include a directory according to this table:

| Platform | Directory |
| --- | --- |
| x86 | `$(VSInstallDir)DIA SDK\lib` |
| x86_64 | `$(VSInstallDir)DIA SDK\lib\amd64` |
| ARM | `$(VSInstallDir)DIA SDK\lib\arm` |
| ARM64 | `$(VSInstallDir)DIA SDK\lib\arm64` |

With the library paths properly added for all target platforms the program now successfully links.

---

As an alternative to setting up the linker environment, this particular issue can also be solved by the compiler: The Microsoft-specific [`__uuidof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uuidof-operator) can retrieve the GUID for interface and class IDs:

```cpp
#include "dia2.h"

int main() { auto const clsid { __uuidof(DiaSource) }; }
```

This will work with MSVC and Clang, though Clang will [issue a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57738113/1889329).

Setting up the linker environment can (be made to) work with any compiler and linker, so that places fewer restrictions on users. And it is strictly required in case you need access to other symbols implemented in `diaguids.lib` (such as `NoRegCoCreate()`).

Comment: or use `__uuidof(DiaSource)` in case msvc c++

Comment: I didn't know that `__uuidof()` works with class IDs as well. Added this alternative to the answer.

Comment: in *dia2.h* exist separate definition `class DECLSPEC_UUID("e6756135-1e65-4d17-8576-610761398c3c") DiaSource;` only because it and "work". the same as `CLSID_DiaSource`

Comment: The mechanics are known to me. I just didn't know (nor expect) that the Visual Studio Team would go out of their way and introduce an identifier (`DiaSource`) for the sole purpose of carrying metadata. That's a nice way of delivering object code to linkers that don't understand [`selectany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/selectany). Thanks for making me aware of this.